# MySQL return 0 if query is null

Tags: mysql

This query should select some statistic values form a table:

```
(SELECT MAX(`id`) as `count` FROM `stats` LIMIT 1)
UNION (SELECT COUNT(*) as `count` FROM `stats` WHERE DATE(`time`) >= (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY) LIMIT 1)
UNION (SELECT COUNT(*) as `count` FROM `stats` WHERE DATE(`time`) >= (NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY) LIMIT 1)
UNION (SELECT COUNT(*) as `count` FROM `stats` WHERE DATE(`time`) >= (NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY) LIMIT 1)
UNION (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(MIN(`time`), '%D of %M, %Y') as `count` FROM `stats` LIMIT 1)
```

I tried this, but it doesn't work

```
(SELECT MAX(`id`) as `count` FROM `stats` LIMIT 1)
UNION IFNULL((SELECT COUNT(*) as `count` FROM `stats` WHERE DATE(`time`) >= (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY) LIMIT 1), '0')
UNION IFNULL((SELECT COUNT(*) as `count` FROM `stats` WHERE DATE(`time`) >= (NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY) LIMIT 1), '0')
UNION IFNULL((SELECT COUNT(*) as `count` FROM `stats` WHERE DATE(`time`) >= (NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY) LIMIT 1), '0')
UNION IFNULL((SELECT DATE_FORMAT(MIN(`time`), '%D of %M, %Y') as `count` FROM `stats` LIMIT 1), '0')
```

Comment: what mean dosen't work .. error.? wrong result? ..

Comment: It returns an error, `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IFNULL((SELECT COUNT(*) as \`count\` FROM \`stats\` WHERE DATE(\`time\`) >= (NOW() - I' at line 2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do `SELECT` on `IFNULL`:

```
SELECT MAX(`id`) as `count` FROM `stats` LIMIT 1
UNION 
SELECT IFNULL((SELECT COUNT(*) as `count` 
               FROM `stats` 
               WHERE DATE(`time`) >= (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY) LIMIT 1), 0)
UNION 
SELECT IFNULL((SELECT COUNT(*) as `count` 
               FROM `stats` 
               WHERE DATE(`time`) >= (NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY) LIMIT 1), 0)
UNION 
SELECT IFNULL((SELECT COUNT(*) as `count` 
               FROM `stats` 
               WHERE DATE(`time`) >= (NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY) LIMIT 1), 0)
UNION 
SELECT IFNULL((SELECT DATE_FORMAT(MIN(`time`), '%D of %M, %Y') as `count` 
               FROM `stats` LIMIT 1), 0)
```

You also have to use `0` instead of '0' and get rid of the parentheses surrounding the first query.